# redirect / на страницу без слеша django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

Есть страницы:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=request.path[:-1])),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)$', PostsDetailView.as_view()),
```

Подскажите как правильно сделать редирект со страницы со слешем на туже страницу без слеша.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Правильно не городить велосипед. Django [по умолчанию добавляет слэш](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH) в конец URL, если его там нет.